# How to detect depth of JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON file that is loaded into my JavaScript and converted to an object. I then take pieces of this object depending on what I need to display, so the part of the object being used is dynamic.

Most of the time the part being used looks something like:

```
"Values": {
    "Var1": "Val1",
    "Var2": "Val2",
    "Var3": "Val3"
}
```

But in rare instances, there are multiple sets like:

```
"Values": {
    "Set1": {
        "Var1": "Val1",
        "Var2": "Val2",
        "Var3": "Val3"
    },
    "Set2": {
        "Var1": "Val1",
        "Var2": "Val2",
        "Var3": "Val3"
    }
}
```

For rendering purposes, I need to detect if the `Values` has sub-sets or not. The number of "VarX"s in each Value/Set may vary, so counting on that is not practical. Likewise, the name of the "SetX"s are not consistent.

The first variable though, SHOULD always be `Var1` but because the order of an object like this is not guaranteed, this is not a satisfactory solution either.

I think the ideal solution is to detect how many dimensions the object is, and go from there. I've tried various methods described online and on SO, but they only seem to count how many total key/values there are, not the dimensions.

Comment: So you want to find the depth of an object basically?

Comment: That's the most reliable solution I can think of. I don't know how to do it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function, it will check the max depth of a simple object:

```
function getDepth (obj) {
    var _index = 0,
        _loop  = function (o) {
            var _childIndex = false,
                _keys       = Object.keys(o);
            _index += 1;
            for (var i in o) {
                if (o[i].toString() == '[object Object]') {
                    _childIndex = i;
                }
                if (_childIndex !== false && i === _keys.reverse()[0]) {
                    _loop(o[i]);
                }
            }
        };
    _loop(obj);
    return _index;
}
```

## Examples:

```
getDepth({
  "Values": {
     "Set1": {
        "Var1": "Val1",
        "Var2": "Val2",
        "Var3": "Val3"
     },
     "Set2": {
        "Var1": "Val1",
        "Var2": "Val2",
        "Var3": "Val3"
     },
    }
});
```

> 2

---

```
getDepth({
  "Values": {
     "Set1": {
        "Var1": "Val1",
        "Var2": "Val2",
        "Var3": "Val3"
     }
    }
});
```

## Cheaty Way

This counts the amount of `{` before a `}`. A bit simpler of a solution:

```
JSON.stringify(myObject)
    .replace(/(["'])((?:(?=(?:(\\))*)\3.|.)*?)\1/g, '')
    .match(/^((?:\{[^}]*)+)/)[1]
    .split("{").length - 1;
```

**Explained**

`JSON.stringify()` makes out object into a string. `.replace` uses a RegEx I made which will take out all strings. This works in *all* cases and supports escaping. The `.match()` will match all `{` until the first `}`. The `split` is used to measure the length of the returned

Comment: When I run this on my object I get `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: @sharf hmm you're right. Give me a minute to fix it

Comment: This works, and I'm trying to dissect it. `Object.keys` could pose a problem for compatibility though. +1 for now, if this ends up being my final solution I'll accept. Thank you!

Comment: This is a great answer and I think will best help others coming here in the future so I'm going to mark it accepted, though I did go with another solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through and check if the property at hand is an object:

```
function isObject (item) {
  return (typeof item === "object" && !Array.isArray(item) && item !== null);
}
```

Using such a function, you can recursively iterate lower until you hit a string.

```
var maxDepth = 0;

var recurse = function(depth) {
  depth = depth || 0;
  depth++;
  maxDepth = (depth) > maxDepth ? depth : maxDepth;
  for (var item in blob) {
    if (blob.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
      if (!isObject(blob[item]) {
        // .. the buck stops here
      } else {
        depth++;
        recurse(depth);
      }
    }
  }
}
recurse(0);
```

You can build off this basic function, but this should give you a basic idea of what I mean.

Comment: When I try this, it doesn't throw an error but just stops all my JS execution dead. Perhaps I'm using it incorrectly. Which variable is my object? I assumed `blob`.

Comment: @sharf I didn't give you a working sample. I gave you an idea of how to solve it, i.e. something you can use to start. As a tip in programming, you are going to get much further and learn far better if you are willing to confront and dive in yourself on this type of thing. Getting into full time cut-and-paste of working code samples only will turn out a terrible programmer in the long run.

Comment: I am a professional web developer, that is my day job. I code my own snippets rather than use libraries most of the time. When I take something from here, I take it apart to learn how it works. I never implement anything from SO before I know how and why it works. I've hit a road block here creating my own, which is why I asked my question.

Comment: Okay got it. "blob" should be your object. You want to wrap my whole code sample in a parent object that passes "blob" in to it.

Comment: The code was stopping dead as I never called `recurse` the first time. I've patched up the function now to be a bit more complete. It should work, or almost work.

Comment: I figured that, because by itself I get a max callstack error. Can you explain a bit about the `for...in` and the `hasOwnProperty` bit? I'm more used to `foreach` type loops (and could maybe figure this out by converting it) but I've heard `for...in` is more economical in JS.

Comment: It's just a clean way to loop an object, as opposed to an array. In the above, `item` refers to the property `key`, such as `Set1`. `blob[item]` would then refer to the `value` of the property. The `blob.hasOwnProperty(item)` is a safety check feature that ensures the object doesn't have wonky properties that you shouldn't be looping. You can google it for more data.

Comment: +1 for the help. I used a variation on your code to come up with a simple solution to my problem, since I only have to detect depth down to 1 or 2 objects. I just think the other answer will be better for other users.